# Create artifacts from environment variables in GO CD

Tags: continuous-integration, go-cd

Using the template system in GO I need to create artifacts from a variable number of environments variables defined in a pipeline.

### Explanation

I have a template for build & deploy repositories. I need to create some  artifacts in the template to be used in another pipeline with fetching artifacts mechanism http://www.go.cd/documentation/user/current/configuration/managing_dependencies.html#fetching-artifacts-from-an-upstream-pipeline.

But repositories could generate a variable number of packages in different locations under the repository tree.

---

Is there any way of generate artifacts in a template based in environment variables defined in the pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way of generate artifacts in a template based in
>   environment variables defined in the pipeline?

For a fixed number of artifacts, yes. You can pass the coordinates of the artifacts to the template as parameters (not environment!) and use the parameters in the template.
XML-scribble:

```
<pipeline name="foo" template="templatename" ...>
  <params>
    <param name="upstream-pipeline">my-pipeline</param>
    <param name="upstream-stage">my-stage</param>
    <param name="upstream-job">my-job</param>
    <param name="upstream-artifacto-directory">my-directory</param>
  </params>
  ...
</pipeline>
```

the template will then do something like that

```
<tasks>
  <fetchartifact artifactOrigin="gocd" srcdir="#{upstream-artifact-directory}" pipeline="#{upstream-pipeline}" stage="#{upstream-stage}" job="#{upstream-job}">
  ...
```

At a certain degree the normal template wizard frontend doesn't allow creating templates with variables. I had to switch over to editing the config.xml directly.

I recommend starting with a working pipeline and then converting it to a template to reduce XML trial & error.